# Segue to self controller releasing data of previous controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionviewcell, uistoryboardsegue

Hi I am developing IOS application. I have one collection view. On click of cell of collection view I am opening same controller with some new data. In this case on first attempt it opening new controller with some new data. But when come back to previous controller and again click on any cell then it gives me error for empty array. That mean it is releasing that data. I tried it in following way:

```
@property(retain, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *relatedArrayList;
assign values in .m file 
on click on cell prepare for segue like this ...
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{

if([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"selfDetailSegue"])
{
    MediaDetailViewController *mediaDetails = [segue destinationViewController];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [[_collectionView indexPathsForSelectedItems] lastObject];
        mediaDetails.videoData = [_relatedArrayList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}
}
```

first time it is working fine. But when I come and click another cell it gives following error

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array'
```

How to retain those values in this scenario? I am doing anything wrong? Need Some help. Thank you.

Comment: Where exactly are you "assigning values in .m file " ?

Comment: When you "come back to previous controller", how do you do it?

Comment: @Riomhaire I am assigning values in .m file it self. I am getting that data from server.

Comment: @PhillipMills thank you for quick replay. I am using push segue. So on click of back click I am coming back to previous segue.

Comment: Can you post where are you initiating your relatedArrayList array. When you click back button viewWillappear will be called. So if your calling server method or initialization  in viewWillAppear, viewDidAppear, then you need to check that out. Please post your viewDidLoad, viewWillAppear, viewDidAppear, and  relatedArrayList population methods. Also check if you are releasing relatedArrayList in viewWillDisappear-viewDidDisappear methods.

Comment: "I am assigning values in .m file it self. I am getting that data from server." - that is too general. I was digging for the same information as @ArunGupta. Please post what he requested.

Comment: If you are using a push, then you are not going **back**!  You're actually adding a new instance of that type of view controller.  As a test, log the value of `self` in `viewWillAppear:`.  If the address changes, then it's not the same object and therefore doesn't contain the same array.

Comment: If you are opening another instance of the same view controller, then a segue doesn't make sense.  Why not simply update the appearance of the current view controller?

Comment: @Paulw11 my situation is little bit different. In which your can redirect to any one of view depending upon condition.

Comment: Ok, then if you are segueing to a new view controller you probably want to supply the whole array to the new VC as well as the selected object - since you are getting an empty array exception

Comment: @Paulw11 but is that true on push segue my previous segue release its data ?

Comment: I am bit of confused of this concept.

Comment: No, but say in you are in an instance of VCA, and it has a property 'array' set to some value.  If you segue to a new instance of VCA you need to make sure that the array property is set again, either via `viewDidLoad` or by setting the property in `prepareForSegue` - it won't have the same values since it is another instance in memory of the same class, not the same instance.

Comment: Yes exactly my new controller contains new set of arrays. only thing is that when I come back to previous VC and again do same action then it is showing empty array for my previous view controller. And also I am not passing array by prepare for segue or something else. My controller has one server call from there I am getting that array data. So once I open new VC it fetch data from server.

Comment: I can do this thing by just maintaining some stack of array which holds my all data.But my only concern is that if my platform is able to do that then no need to do manually.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67691/discussion-between-paulw11-and-nilkash).

Answer (score -1):

Reinit or allocate arraylist, assign the values and try again.

Comment: Not getting your solution sir. Actually If I open other controller instead of same controller then it is working fine.But if I open same controller then it is giving error.

Comment: Ok, if you see the line you have posted some time back, and as per understanding u r trying to create new reference everytime using "MediaDetailViewController *mediaDetails = [segue destinationViewController];", so for new class reference you should have new reference of array as well.